# Error 400 al hacer un post con una api

Tags: c#, api, .net, asp.net-web-api

espero que bien, estoy tratando de enviar una boleta electronica de mi país con una api, pero sale error 400, diciendo que falta un parametro, el rutCompany, pero está.
Aquí les dejo lo que tengo:

```
public async Task<Tuple<int, int, string>> enviarBoleta2(string codigoEmpresa,
                string rut,
                string dv,
                string dvrutreplegal,
                string dvrutreplegal,
                string tipodoc, string numerodoc, byte[] xmlBytes, string cookieValue)
    {
   
        string filename = "Envio_DTE_T39_F" + numerodoc + ".xml";          

        var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.UseCookies = false;

        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://rahue.sii.cl/recursos/v1/boleta.electronica.envio"))
            {
                request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Expect", "100-continue");
                request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("accept", "application/json");
                request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 ( compatible; PROG 1.0; Windows NT)");
                request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Cookie", "TOKEN=" + cookieValue);

                var multipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                multipartContent.Add(new StringContent(rutreplegal), "rutSender");
                multipartContent.Add(new StringContent(dvrutreplegal), "dvSender");
                multipartContent.Add(new StringContent(rut), "rutCompany");
                multipartContent.Add(new StringContent(dv), "dvCompany");
                var file1 = new ByteArrayContent(xmlBytes);
                file1.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/xml");
                multipartContent.Add(file1, "archivo", filename);
                request.Content = multipartContent;

                var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
                var respuesta = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
        }

        return Tuple.Create(retorno, 1, mensaje);
    }
```

En el response me dice esto:
**{StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Peticion con error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:{  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *  Server-Timing: dtSInfo;desc="0", dtRpid;desc="-1464696460"  Connection: close  Date: Sat, 19 Aug 2023 20:14:13 GMT  Set-Cookie: dtCookie=v_4_srv_43_sn_59015DF0C55CF290F61B5633FEC88802_perc_100000_ol_0_mul_1_app-3Aea7c4b59f27d43eb_0; Path=/; Domain=.sii.cl  Server: version  Server: 1.1  Server: version  Server: 1.2  Server: Apache  Content-Length: 17  Content-Language: es  Content-Type: text/plain}}**

en la variable respuesta me dice que Falta rutCompany
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la documentación de la api, pide esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el link de donde indica la documentación de la api en .
https://www4c.sii.cl/bolcoreinternetui/api/
Al seleccionar /boleta.electronica.envio

Si alguien sabe algo, les agradecería su respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: Que valor tiene la variable rut?

Comment: @Yussef, hola, el valor que tiene es 10869979

Comment: @Yussef, para que preguntas?

Comment: Porque tu recibes el rut como `string` y el SII lo requiere como `int`, pensé que quizás te estaba llegando con puntos y/o guion y eso es lo que causa el problema, pero no es así